# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::save()?

Tags: laravel-4, eloquent

I'm getting this error after trying to save my model. This is the error I'm getting:

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::save()

This is my code:

```
public function getActivate ($code)
{
    $user = User::where('code','=',$code)->where('active','=',0);

    if ($user->count())
    {
        $user->first();
        //Update user to active state
        $user->active = 1;
        $user->code ='';

        if($user->save()) 
        {
            return Redirect::route('home')
                            ->with('global', 'Account Activated ! You can sign in ');
        }
    }

    return Redirect::route('home')
                    ->with('global', 'We could not activate your account. Try again later');
}
```

My version of Laravel is the stable one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is you are not getting the first instance of your user, and you are just calling the `save()` on the query itself.

Here is the updated code:

```
public function getActivate ($code)
{
    $user = User::where('code','=',$code)->where('active','=',0)->first();

    if ($user)
    {
        //Update user to active state
        $user->active = 1;
        $user->code ='';

        if($user->save()) 
        {
            return Redirect::route('home')
                            ->with('global', 'Account Activated ! You can sign in ');
        }
    }

    return Redirect::route('home')
                    ->with('global', 'We could not activate your account. Try again later');
}
```

Also, you may simplify your query build by replacing `where($column, '=', $query)` to

```
$user = User::whereCode($code)->whereActive(0)->first();
```